# Need help solving an issue in CListBox

Tags: c++, mfc, clistbox

I'm still learning C++ MFC and my question is: how can I get the `CurSel` of 2 listbox as the number, then add them and print the result?
The result displays a weird 659998896 number instead of 2. What have I done wrong here?

```
BOOL CEngravingCalculatorDlg::OnInitDialog(){
    CListBox* emplistbox1 = static_cast<CListBox*>(GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1));
    emplistbox1->AddString(L"1");
    emplistbox1->SetCurSel(0);

    CListBox* emplistbox3 = static_cast<CListBox*>(GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST3));
    emplistbox3->AddString(L"1");
    emplistbox3->SetCurSel(0);
    }

void CEngravingCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
   CListBox* emplistbox1 = static_cast<CListBox*>(GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1));
   CListBox* emplistbox3 = static_cast<CListBox*>(GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST3));
   int num1 = emplistbox1->GetCurSel();
   int num2 = emplistbox3->GetCurSel();
   int equal = num1 + num2;
   CString str;
   str.Format(_T("%d", equal));
    GetDlgItem(IDC_Display)->SetWindowTextW(str);
}
```

Comment: Do you define these `emplistbox1` _etc_ pointers anywhere other than in the local function? I ask because in your click event handler, you acquire a pointer to `emplistbox2` but then call `emplistbox3->GetCurSel()` -- there is no such variable as `emplistbox3` in that function. Additionally, you're accessing `IDC_LIST2` which was never configured on dialog init. Please look over your code carefully and resolve all copy/paste mistakes.

Comment: oops, it's a typo. I edited it, thanks

Comment: What is it that you expect `_T("%d", equal)` to do?

Comment: The compiler was [telling you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4002) what's wrong. Don't ignore warnings.

Answer (score 3):

`_T` is a macro that takes only a single parameter.  Because of a typo, you've given it two parameters.  The second one is ignored and effectively lost.  This means your `format` call is only getting a single parameter, and you're seeing undefined behavior.  Fix it with:

```
str.Format(_T("%d"), equal);
```

P.S. This means your error had absolutely nothing to do with the listbox.

Comment: seccpur just solved what I have done wrong and I understand now. I'm support to getText, not the parameter. That's why it calculates weird.

Comment: @Unknown that just means you were doing **two** things wrong.

Comment: @Unknown the only reason seccpur's code works is they replaced the macro with a proper string literal.

Answer (score 3):

See this snippet. `GetCurSel()` is used to get the cursor position and not the content. Use `GetText()` to get the content of the Listbox.

```
void CEngravingCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    CListBox* emplistbox1 = static_cast<CListBox*>(GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1));
    CListBox* emplistbox3 = static_cast<CListBox*>(GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST3));
    int num1 = emplistbox1->GetCurSel();
    int num2 = emplistbox3->GetCurSel();

    CString ItemSelected1, ItemSelected2;
    if (num1 != LB_ERR && num2 != LB_ERR)   {
        emplistbox1->GetText(num1, ItemSelected1);      
        emplistbox3->GetText(num2, ItemSelected2);      

        int equal = atoi(CStringA(ItemSelected1).GetString()) + atoi(CStringA(ItemSelected2).GetString());
        CString str;
        str.Format(L"%d", equal);
        SetDlgItemText(IDC_Display, str);
    }

}
```